# MemoryError when performing cross-validation using scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to do some SVM classification on some dicom images - size (91, 109, 91)). There are 400 images in total and each subject is either healthy (0) or has a positive scan (1)

I have written a simple bit of code to loop through all dicoms in a directory, get the pixel counts and pass them to a numpy array and flatten the array. For each dicom file I lookup a csv file with image status 0 or 1 and add these to the numpy array. At the end of this loop I have a 2d numpy array, with pixel counts and status for each patient in a single row of the numpy array.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import dicom
import sklearn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import svm
import csv
import re


dirName = '/home/nm/MachineLearning/DaTSCAN/PPMI/'
# Name of csv file
results_dat='PPMIdatabase.csv'
results_path=os.path.join("/",dirName,results_dat)

# make an empty array that we will populate with dicom image array values
data = []

for filename in os.listdir(dirName):
    dicom_file = os.path.join("/",dirName,filename)  

    if os.path.isfile(dicom_file) and filename.endswith(".dcm"):
        try:
            # check for study in csv file to get diagnosis
            #Get study number from dicom string
            study_id = int(re.search(r'\d+', filename).group())            
            with open(results_path, 'r') as file:
                reader = csv.reader(file)
                search_group = [line[1] for line in reader if line[0] == str(study_id)]
                group = str(search_group[0])
                #HC 0 # PD 1
                if group == 'HC':
                    group_id = 0
                else:
                    group_id = 1
            ds = dicom.read_file(dicom_file)
            img = ds.pixel_array
            a = np.reshape(img,[img.size,1],'C')
            # Add group_id to a
            a = np.insert(a,0,group_id)
            data.append(a)
        except InvalidDicomError:
            print("File %s cannot be opened by dicom.read_file" %(filename))

#make python list to numpy array
full_data = np.array(data)

# Want to predict Y
Y = full_data[:,0] # first row of array is classification status 0 or 1
# Image data
X = full_data[:, 1:]
```

I would then like to run cross validation to evaluate estimator performance (using `scikitlearn`)

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.4,random_state=0)

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(X_train, y_train)

clf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

However I am met with the following error which suggests a memory issue

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cross_validation.py", line 56, in <module>
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.4,random_state=0)
  File "/home/nm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 1919, in train_test_split
    safe_indexing(a, test)) for a in arrays))
  File "/home/nm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 1919, in <genexpr>
    safe_indexing(a, test)) for a in arrays))
  File "/home/nm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 163, in safe_indexing
    return X.take(indices, axis=0)
MemoryError
```

Is my numpy array too large. How can I get around this?

Comment: Could you confirm what `full_data.shape` and `full_data.dtype` are? How much RAM do you have?

Comment: @ali_m dtype is int16 and 8Gb of RAM

Comment: shape is (400, 902630)

Comment: Given those dimensions and dtype, `X` will be 722MB, and `X_train` and `X_test` will consume an additional 433MB and 288MB respectively (the `Y`s are trivially small in comparison). I can't see any reason why you would encounter a `MemoryError` here unless you either have less than ~722MB of free memory at the time you call `train_test_split`, or your description of the arrays is somehow inaccurate.

Comment: These array sizes could become a problem with a 32-bit Python, I think especially on Windows.

Comment: @moarningsun based on the paths it doesn't look like the OP is using Windows, but I suppose it could still be 32bit Python.

Comment: Hi it is a 32bit python running on xubuntu

Comment: Well, there you go! Your 32-bit Python process can't address more than 2GB of memory regardless of how much RAM you have installed. The most likely explanation for the MemoryError you are seeing is that you are hitting this limit. You should switch to a 64-bit version of Python (and a 64-bit OS, if you are using 32-bit Xubuntu).

Comment: Unfortunately not an option as I have a 32 bit processor

Comment: Tried SGDClassifier with hinge loss? using partial_fit method ?